# How to set different author/committer for Git in TRAMP environment?

Tags: git, emacs, tramp

I edit files under Git control with Emacs 23.3.1/TRAMP/VC sudoed over an ssh connection (`/sudo:sudouser@host:file` with `tramp-default-proxies-alist` set accordingly).  `sudouser` is a shared account, so I don't want to set `user.email`/`user.name` globally, but instead use `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME`/`GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL`/`GIT_COMMITTER_NAME`/`GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL` to set it just for my connection.

I did not find a way to set an environment/change the command in `vc-git` itself.  Adding the environment variables to `tramp-remote-process-environment`:

```
(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-process-environment "GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL=tim@tim-landscheidt.de")
(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-process-environment "GIT_AUTHOR_NAME='Tim Landscheidt'")
(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-process-environment "GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=tim@tim-landscheidt.de")
(add-to-list 'tramp-remote-process-environment "GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL='Tim Landscheidt'")
```

works, but I fear it might bite me in the future when I want to work on a host where I need another identity.

Is there a way to set a different author/committer limited to one TRAMP connection?

Answer (score 2):

I know nothing of TRAMP, but I can point out that you can set `user.email` and `user.name` individually for a particular repository by setting them in `.git/config` or by doing the commands:

```
git config --local user.name "Tim Landscheidt"
git config --local user.email "tim@tim-landscheidt.de"
```

So that way you can have different settings for author/committer for each repository.

Comment: Whether the identity is set in `~/.gitconfig` or `.git/config` doesn't matter; the problem is that it is a shared account, and I don't want others (accidentally) posing as myself.